# Python - Add the smallest value from each row of an ndarray to a list. If the smallest number is already in list , then add next smallest

Tags: python, list, numpy-ndarray

Say I have a 4x4 array, each row already sorted by smallest value. I want to create a list with the minimum values from each array row without repeating a value. So if a minimum value is already in the list, we should take the next smallest value and add it to the list.

Each row of the array is already sorted by smallest values

```
set=[ [1,10,20,30],[10,50,60,70],[10,20,50,60],[1,20,25,65] ]
A=np.asarray(set) #A[0,0] = 1 ; A[3,3] = 65
minval=[] #list to append min values to
```

so the final list would be [1,10,20,25]

I started by trying to iterate through A[i,j] and appending to minval if it's not in minval, but that's not even working. After that, I wouldn't know how to break the loop once we append a value from A[i]

```
minval=[]
for i in A: #expect A[0] through A[3]
    for j in A[i]: #expect A[0,0] through A[3,3]
        minval.append(A[i,j]) if A[i,j] not in minval else minval
```

this already gives me an error because the first value for i is an array rather than y[0] like i'd expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each row is already sorted by smallest value, we can do this:

```
list = [ [1, 10, 20, 30], [10, 50, 60, 70], [10, 20, 50, 60], [1, 20, 25, 65] ]
new_list = []

for row in list:
    for col in row:
        if col not in new_list:
            new_list.append(col)
            break
```

Comment: Great! So I created the ndarray using a list above for recreation purposed. If I'm starting with an ndarray, A, then I would just do A.tolist() then loop through the sorted lists. Thanks!